# ExpandableCardView Text Not Fully Visible

Tags: android, textview, android-cardview, expandable

I am using [this library](https://github.com/AleSpero/ExpandableCardView) to achieve expandable cards and it works fine except for two major concerns viz:

1. It requires the min api level to be 21 and previously my min api level was 16. Will this work well on lower devices. There's an option to override this in the library's manifest file but I don't think it's a good idea.
2. I have layout like below which contains another layout with a textview but the text is not showing fully, only the first line is visible. Here's the layout:

   ```
        <com.alespero.expandablecardview.ExpandableCardView
               android:id="@+id/focusCardLayout"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_below="@+id/metaCard"
               android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
               app:expandOnClick="true"
               app:inner_view="@layout/session_inner_card_focus_pts_layout"
               app:title="Focus Points" />
   ```

and the `inner_view` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/focusPointsTV"
   android:layout_margin="5dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
   android:text="You cannot win matches without scoring points so it's important your players can shoot accurately."
   android:textSize="18sp"
   android:padding="10dp">

 </TextView>
```

Is this a fault in my layout or the library. I have set input_type to short/long message, still no effect.
Is there other means of `expanding-collapsing` cardviews android? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code, and I think your issue come from the library.

I know a lib that resolve your issue as well, that is [this library](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView)

```
<!-- sample xml -->
  <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/expand_text_view"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="4"
      expandableTextView:animDuration="200">
      <TextView
          android:id="@id/expandable_text"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
          android:textSize="16sp"
          android:textColor="#666666" />
      <ImageButton
          android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:padding="16dp"
          android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
          android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
  </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
```

It's work for me and I hope it will help you too.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it out